# HTTP caching WCF REST/SOAP action using WebInvoke

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, soap, outputcache

I have a WCF Web Service (not Web Api) that looks like this:

```
public interface ILogsService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Find")]
    [Description("-Service description-")]
    FindLogsResult FindLogs(LogsFilterRequest request);
}
```

I would like to know if there's a way (or a better way) to cache the service response by sending HTTP cache headers back to the client.

I've tested and seen that this can be accomplished by using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));
```

But I would like a "cleaner" solution if possible.

This service has `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"` and will always be hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, the only way I could get this working was via HTTP Context:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add a cache attribute to your method:

```
[AspNetCacheProfile("CacheMediumTerm")]
public FindLogsResult FindLogs(LogsFilterRequest request) {
    //...
```

Which you can then configure in your config file:

```
<!-- ...  -->
<system.web>
   <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
         <outputCacheProfiles>
            <add name="CacheMediumTerm" duration="120" varyByParam="none" sqlDependency="MyTestDatabase:MyTable"/>
         </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
   </caching>
   <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
```

More information on this feature is available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx

Comment: I tried, but it wont allow me since I'm using `WebInvoke` (not `WebGet`)

Comment: Ah - sorry, it can't work with WebInvoke :( - it might be the manual headers after all!